# First EmailMessage Status Updated From "New" to "Read" when there is update to Parent Case

Tags: trigger, email, visual-workflow, email2case

I am using Email-To-Case service and every time there is incoming emails, Salesforce automatically create Email Message with status 0 (New) and new case created as parent of that Email.

But when the parent case gets updated (either in same transaction or not). The **First Email Message** (only first) status from that case automatically updated from 0 to 1 (New to Read).

Is anyone aware of this behavior? and is there any Salesforce documentation related this behavior? AFAIK the latest documentation only state that EmailMessage status updated from New to Read when someone open the case detail page (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=000386995&type=1)

I have a use case where I need to inspect the email content and update case information based on the email content. But I am not expecting the EmailMessage is automatically updated to "Read" by trigger since the EmailMessage should be "Read" by user not by system.